# data flowing from column to row in HTML

Tags: html, css, unix

I have a scenario . I have a table in which there are 2 columns and 10 rows.
I have to fill all the rows of first column and then all the rows of another column.
but when I am creating it is just adding the value of column2 after column1. Is it possible in HTML CSS?

eg

```
Id  Name
1   Onkar
2   Tiwari
3   Shweta
```

I want to fill all the values of `id` column first then all the values of `name` column. Actually `id` column is getting passed by unix.

Could you please help me to do the same?

what i did

```
                                 <table>

                                <tr class="row2-column1" >
                                        <td>Axiom index</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row2-column2">
                                        <td>Cob Date </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row2-column3">
                                    <td>   Run Id </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row2-column4">
                                      <td>  is_month_end </td>
                                </tr>


                                <td>    %jobs_status1% </td>
                        </tr>
                         </table>
  This jobs_status  value is coming from unix. rows are 16 and columns are 2.
```

Comment: Can the row be (way) more than 10? What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks...I have added in the question.

Comment: have you tried my answer @OnkarTiwari ?

Comment: Thank you @fcaldren . yes i tried and it worked. i visited this page today only after that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with a simple `animation` of the `color` property with a progressive delay for each `<td>`. The final effect is a sequential print of columns and rows.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdZJMr)

e.g.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>1</td><td>Name 1</td>
    </tr>
    ...    
    <tr>
       <td>10</td><td>Name 10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
tbody td { 
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0); 
  animation: colorize .15s linear 0s forwards;
}

@keyframes colorize {
  from { color: rgba(0,0,0, 0);  }
  to { color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);  }
}

/* first column */
tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 1s; }
tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 1.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 2s; }
tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 2.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(5) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 3s; }
tr:nth-of-type(6) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 3.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(7) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 4s; }
tr:nth-of-type(8) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 4.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(9) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(10) td:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 5.5s; }


/* second column */
tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 6s; }
tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 6.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 7s; }
tr:nth-of-type(4) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 7.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(5) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 8s; }
tr:nth-of-type(6) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 8.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(7) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 9s; }
tr:nth-of-type(8) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 9.5s; }
tr:nth-of-type(9) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 10s; }
tr:nth-of-type(10) td:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: 10.5s; }
```

Of course if you plan to have (way) more than 10 rows you should generate the `animation-delay` with some tools like `less` or `sass` (doing it by hand could be a tedious task).